# read file and extract variables based on what is in the line

Tags: awk, sed

I have a file that looks like this:

```
$ cat file_test
garbage text A=one B=two C=three D=four
garbage text A= B=six D=seven
garbage text A=eight E=nine D=ten B=eleven
```

I want to go through each line and extract specific "variables" to use in the loop. And if a line doesn't have a variable then set it to an empty string.

So, for the above example, lets say I want to extract the variables `A`, `B`, and `C`, then for each line, the loop would have this:

1. `garbage text A=one B=two C=three D=four`

   - `A` = "one"
   - `B` = "two"
   - `C` = "three"
2. `garbage text A= B=six D=seven`

   - `A` = ""
   - `B` = "six"
   - `C` = ""
3. `garbage text A=eight E=nine D=ten B=eleven`

   - `A` = "eight"
   - `B` = "eleven"
   - `C` = ""

My original plan was to use `sed` but that won't work since the order of the "variables" is not consistent (the last line for example) and a "variable" may be missing (the second line for example).

My next thought is to go through line by line, then split the line into fields using `awk` and set variables based on each field but I have no clue where or how to start.

I'm open to other ideas or better suggestions.

Comment: Okay... once you make the variables, then what? You should at least show your efforts.

Comment: I haven't gotten that far. I don't know how to extract the variables.

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan, From your post I understood that you need to grab values of strings and use them as shell variables for your further tasks, is that correct? Or you want to simply print their values?

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan : If you really want to do it in bash (IMO the Perl solution posted by tshiono is more attractive), I would  use a nested loop: The outer one loops over the lines. The inner one loops over the variables to extract. Use bash regular expressions to extract the value of the respective variable. If the variable does not exist, set it to empty.

Comment: (Off topic) After seeing these answers, I think this question is eligible to migrate to [PCG](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

right answer depends on what you're going to do with the variables.

assuming you need them as shell variables, here is a different approach

```
$ while IFS= read -r line; 
  do A=""; B=""; C=""; 
     source <(echo "$line" | grep -oP "(A|B|C)=\w*" ); 
     echo "A=$A B=$B C=$C"; 
  done < file

A=one B=two C=three
A= B=six C=
A=eight B=eleven C=
```

the trick is using `source` for variable declarations extracted from each line with `grep`. Since value assignments carry over, you need to reset them before each new line.

Answer (score 0):

On my first 3 solutions, I am considering that your need to use shell variables from the values of strings `A,B,C` and you do not want to simply print them, if this is the case then following(s) may help you.

---

---

***1st Solution:*** It considers that your variables `A,B,C` are always coming in same field number.

```
while read first second third fourth fifth sixth
do
  echo $third,$fourth,$fifth        ##Printing values here.
  a_var=${third#*=}
  b_var=${fourth#*=}
  c_var=${fifth#*=}
  echo "Using new values of variables here...."
  echo "NEW A="$a_var
  echo "NEW B="$b_var
  echo "NEW C="$c_var
done < "Input_file"
```

It is simply printing the variables values in each line since you have NOT told what use you are going to do with these variables so I am simply printing them you could use them as per your use case too.

---

---

***2nd solution:*** This considers that variables are coming in same order but it does check if A is coming on 3rd place or not, B is coming on 4th place or not etc and prints accordingly.

```
while read first second third fourth fifth sixth
do
  echo $third,$fourth,$fifth        ##Printing values here.
  a_var=$(echo "$third" | awk '$0 ~ /^A/{sub(/.*=/,"");print}')
  b_var=$(echo "$fourth" | awk '$0 ~ /^B/{sub(/.*=/,"");print}')
  c_var=$(echo "$fifth" | awk '$0 ~ /^C/{sub(/.*=/,"");print}')
  echo "Using new values of variables here...."
  echo "NEW A="$a_var
  echo "NEW B="$b_var
  echo "NEW C="$c_var
done < "Input_file"
```

---

---

***3rd Solution:*** Which looks perfect FIT for your requirement, not sure how much efficient from coding vice(I am still analyzing more if we could do something else here too). This code will NOT look for `A`,`B`, or `C`'s order in line it will match it let them be anywhere in line, if match found it will assign value of variable OR else it will be NULL value.

```
while read line
do
  a_var=$(echo "$line" | awk 'match($0,/A=[^ ]*/){val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);sub(/.*=/,"",val);print val}')
  b_var=$(echo "$line" | awk 'match($0,/B=[^ ]*/){val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);sub(/.*=/,"",val);print val}')
  c_var=$(echo "$line" | awk 'match($0,/C=[^ ]*/){val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);sub(/.*=/,"",val);print val}')
  echo "Using new values of variables here...."
  echo "NEW A="$a_var
  echo "NEW B="$b_var
  echo "NEW C="$c_var
done < "Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
Using new values of variables here....
NEW A=one
NEW B=two
NEW C=three
Using new values of variables here....
NEW A=
NEW B=six
NEW C=
Using new values of variables here....
NEW A=eight
NEW B=eleven
NEW C=
```

---

---

***EDIT1:*** In case you simply want to print values of `A,B,C` then try following.

```
awk '{
 for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
   if($i ~ /[ABCabc]=/){
     sub(/.*=/,"",$i)
     a[++count]=$i
   }
 }
 print "A="a[1] ORS "B=" a[2] ORS "C="a[3];count=""
 delete a
}'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

If `perl` is your option, please try:

```
perl -ne 'undef %a; while (/([\w]+)=([\w]*)/g) {$a{$1}=$2;}
    for ("A", "B", "C") {print "$_=\"$a{$_}\"\n";}' file_test
```

Output:

```
A="one"
B="two"
C="three"
A=""
B="six"
C=""
A="eight"
B="eleven"
C=""
```

It parses each line for assignments with `=`, store the key-value pair in an assoc array `%a`, then finally reports the values for A, B and C.

Answer (score 0):

I'm partial to the `awk` solution, e.g.

```
$ awk '{for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) if ($i ~ /^[A-Za-z_][^=]*[=]/) print $i}' file
A=one
B=two
C=three
D=four
A=
B=six
D=seven
A=eight
E=nine
D=ten
B=eleven
```

**Explanation**

- `for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++)` loop over each space separated field;
- `if ($i ~ /^[A-Za-z_][^=]*[=]/)` if the field begins with at least one character that is `[A-Za-z_]` followed by an `'='`; then
- `print $i` print the field.

Comment: why is underscore part of regex match?  I think it should be just `[ABC]=` based on OP's spec.

Comment: Well, honestly, it was because the shell can start a variable with it. (or at least that was my thought process) Sticking with `[A-Za-z]` would be fine, but then I know somebody would say -- hey, you can use an `'_'` too `:)` But, yes, I agree, to tailor it to the input `[A-Z]` would be all that was required.

Comment: OK, you want to extract **all** possible variable assignments.

Comment: Yep, exactly. I was trying to make it reasonably broad to accommodate any `C=foo a=bar b=baz ...` that may come later in the file.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, cool solution. IMHO if you see my EDIT2 solution we both have same approach only thing I have kept values in arrays to print NULL values of `A,B,C` too else if any letter is missing from line then it will not print NULL value of it.

Comment: Yes, I see that and just tried it. That's indeed is a cool way to keep track of the sequential lettering. Depends on how he needs to use it. If there is a chance that any of the unnamed sequential letters are defined above the file inclusion and then used after at some point, I could see a hiccup, but other than that, I like it and tucked it into my toolbox.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, Wow, great. You have noted down my code(really?) 1 of the great member on SO(you sir), OMG you made my day sir. But I didn't get about hiccup part  in code, could you please explain it more, will be grateful to you.

Comment: The only thought there was let's say he has a script. And for whatever reason he know that the variables in the file he is parsing won't conflict with any that already exist in his script. Now let's say he has a `B=something` defined at the top of his script and there is no `B` in the data file we parse, but if we include `B=` as a sequential letter, and set it empty when that wasn't expected, I could see that causing an issue if he later in is script used `B` thinking it was still set. I'm not saying that's likely, but just one thought that popped into my mind when I thought about it `:)`

Answer (score 0):

Another Perl

```
perl -lne ' %x = /(\S+)=(\S+)/g ; for("A","B","C") { print "$_ = $x{$_}" } %x=() '
```

with the input file

```
$ perl -lne ' %x = /(\S+)=(\S+)/g ; for("A","B","C") { print "$_ = $x{$_}" } %x=() ' file_test
A = one
B = two
C = three
A =
B = six
C =
A = eight
B = eleven
C =
$
```

Answer (score 0):

a generic variable awk seld documented.
Assuming variable separator are `=` and not part of text before nor variable content itself.

```
awk 'BEGIN {
        # load the list of variable and order to print
        VarSize = split( "A B C", aIdx )
        # create a pattern filter for variable catch in lines
        for ( Idx in aIdx ) VarEntry = ( VarEntry ? ( VarEntry "|^" ) : "^" ) aIdx[Idx] "="
        }

        {
        # reset varaible value
        split( "", aVar )
        # for each part of the line
        for ( Fld=1; Fld<=NF; Fld++ ) {
           # if part is a varaible assignation
           if( $Fld ~ VarEntry ) {
              # separate variable name and content in array
              split( $Fld, aTemp, /=/ )
              # put variable content in corresponding varaible name container
              aVar[aTemp[1]] = aTemp[2]
              }
           }
        # print all variable content (empty or not) found on this line
        for ( Idx in aIdx ) printf( "%s = \042%s\042\n", aIdx[Idx], aVar[aIdx[Idx]] )
        }
      ' YourFile
```

Answer (score 0):

Its unclear whether you're trying to set awk variables or shell variables but here's how to populate an associative awk array and then use that to populate an associative shell array:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    numKeys = split("A B C",keys)
}
{
    delete f
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        if ( split($i,t,/=/) == 2 ) {
            f[t[1]] = t[2]
        }
    }
    for (keyNr=1; keyNr<=numKeys; keyNr++) {
        key = keys[keyNr]
        printf "[%s]=\"%s\"%s", key, f[key], (keyNr<numKeys ? OFS : ORS)
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
[A]="one" [B]="two" [C]="three"
[A]="" [B]="six" [C]=""
[A]="eight" [B]="eleven" [C]=""

$  while IFS= read -r out; do declare -A arr="( $out )"; declare -p arr; done < <(awk -f tst.awk file)
declare -A arr=([A]="one" [B]="two" [C]="three" )
declare -A arr=([A]="" [B]="six" [C]="" )
declare -A arr=([A]="eight" [B]="eleven" [C]="" )

$ echo "${arr["A"]}"
eight
```